# Set specific value to round corners of UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I know there are some similar questions like this, but in my case, I want to set cornerRadius = 8 for my layer.

[image]

If I set:

```
shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
```

it shows like this:

[image]

-> Not match as the design.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class OnboardingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var boxView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIView!

  var onTap: (() -> Void)?
  var levelProgress: CGFloat = 0.1 {
    didSet {
      fgLayer.strokeEnd = levelProgress
    }
  }

  let bgLayer = CAShapeLayer()
  let fgLayer = CAShapeLayer()

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setup()
    configure()
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setupShapeLayer(shapeLayer: bgLayer)
    setupShapeLayer(shapeLayer: fgLayer)
  }

  private func setup() {
    bgLayer.lineWidth = 50
    bgLayer.fillColor = nil
    bgLayer.strokeStart = 470 / 1590 + 0.008
    bgLayer.strokeEnd = 1
    bgLayer.cornerRadius = 8
    progressView.layer.addSublayer(bgLayer)
    fgLayer.lineWidth = 50
    fgLayer.fillColor = nil
    fgLayer.strokeStart = 0
    fgLayer.strokeEnd = 470 / 1590 - 0.008
    progressView.layer.addSublayer(fgLayer)
  }

  private func configure() {
    bgLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xE3EDF7).cgColor
    fgLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x18D4F4).cgColor
  }

  private func setupShapeLayer(shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
    let linePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: progressView.bounds.midX, y: progressView.bounds.midY), radius: progressView.frame.height / 2, startAngle: 9/11 * CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 2/11 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    linePath.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    boxView.addFloatEffect()
    continueButton.addFloatEffectForButton()
    bgLayer.addSankEffect()
    fgLayer.addFloatEffect()
  }

  @IBAction func continueButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    onTap?()
  }
}
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: I've just updated.

Comment: add `bgLayer.masksToBounds  = true`

Comment: I tried, not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cornerRadius` only adjusts the corners of the bounds of the layer, not of the path. If you want path with rounded corners, you’ll have to stroke that yourself.

There are two approaches to rendering an arc with a particular corner radius:

1. If rendering a simple solid rendition, one very simple approach is to render two arcs, one clockwise, one counter clockwise, using different radii. The line width of these individual arcs should be twice the desired corner rounding of the final shape. Then, if you render these two arcs with a matching stroke color and fill color, you’ll get the desired shape.

   Here it is, animated so you can see what’s going on:

   [image]

   This is the code (without the animation):

   ```
   class ArcView: UIView {
       var startAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 3 / 4
       var endAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 5 / 4
       var clockwise: Bool = true

       /// Radius of center of this arc
       var radius: CGFloat = 100

       /// The linewidth of this thick arc
       var lineWidth: CGFloat = 50

       /// The corner radius of this thick arc
       var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10

       static override var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }
       var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return layer as! CAShapeLayer }

       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           updatePath()
       }

       func updatePath() {
           let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
           let innerRadius = radius - lineWidth / 2 + cornerRadius
           let innerAngularDelta = asin(cornerRadius / innerRadius) * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           let outerRadius = radius + lineWidth / 2 - cornerRadius
           let outerAngularDelta = asin(cornerRadius / outerRadius) * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)

           let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: startAngle + innerAngularDelta, endAngle: endAngle - innerAngularDelta, clockwise: clockwise)
           path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: endAngle - outerAngularDelta, endAngle: startAngle + outerAngularDelta, clockwise: !clockwise)
           path.close()

           // configure shapeLayer

           shapeLayer.lineWidth = cornerRadius * 2
           shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
           shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
           shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
           shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
       }

   }
   ```

   The only trick in the above is how to adjust the starting and ending angles of these inner and outer arcs such that they’ll be perfectly circumscribed by the desired final shape. But a little trigonometry can be used to figure out those angular deltas, as shown above.
2. The other approach is to define a path for the outline of the desired shape. Calculating the inner arc and outer arcs is similar, but you have to manually calculate the angles for the four rounded corners. It’s just a little trigonometry, but it’s a little hairy:

   ```
   class ArcView: UIView {
       var startAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 3 / 4
       var endAngle: CGFloat = .pi * 5 / 4
       var clockwise: Bool = true

       /// Radius of center of this arc
       var radius: CGFloat = 100

       /// The linewidth of this thick arc
       var lineWidth: CGFloat = 100

       /// The corner radius of this thick arc
       var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10

       static override var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }
       var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return layer as! CAShapeLayer }

       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           updatePath()
       }

       func updatePath() {
           let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
           let innerRadius = radius - lineWidth / 2
           let innerAngularDelta = asin(cornerRadius / (innerRadius + cornerRadius)) * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           let outerRadius = radius + lineWidth / 2
           let outerAngularDelta = asin(cornerRadius / (outerRadius - cornerRadius)) * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)

           let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: startAngle + innerAngularDelta, endAngle: endAngle - innerAngularDelta, clockwise: clockwise)

           var angle = endAngle - innerAngularDelta
           var cornerStartAngle = angle + .pi * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           var cornerEndAngle = endAngle + .pi / 2 * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           var cornerCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + (innerRadius + cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (innerRadius + cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
           path.addArc(withCenter: cornerCenter, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: cornerStartAngle, endAngle: cornerEndAngle, clockwise: !clockwise)

           angle = endAngle - outerAngularDelta
           cornerStartAngle = cornerEndAngle
           cornerEndAngle = endAngle - outerAngularDelta
           cornerCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + (outerRadius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (outerRadius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
           path.addArc(withCenter: cornerCenter, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: cornerStartAngle, endAngle: cornerEndAngle, clockwise: !clockwise)

           path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: endAngle - outerAngularDelta, endAngle: startAngle + outerAngularDelta, clockwise: !clockwise)

           angle = startAngle + outerAngularDelta
           cornerStartAngle = angle
           cornerEndAngle = startAngle - .pi / 2 * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           cornerCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + (outerRadius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (outerRadius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
           path.addArc(withCenter: cornerCenter, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: cornerStartAngle, endAngle: cornerEndAngle, clockwise: !clockwise)

           angle = startAngle + innerAngularDelta
           cornerStartAngle = cornerEndAngle
           cornerEndAngle = angle + .pi * (clockwise ? 1 : -1)
           cornerCenter = CGPoint(x: center.x + (innerRadius + cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (innerRadius + cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
           path.addArc(withCenter: cornerCenter, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: cornerStartAngle, endAngle: cornerEndAngle, clockwise: !clockwise)

           path.close()

           // configure shapeLayer

           shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
           shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
           shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
           shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think in my case it will be complicated cuz I have to set the inner and outer shadow for the circle.

Comment: @Khuong - That’s why I gave you the second rendition. It should work with those shadows.

Comment: Hi @Rob, your second solution works for me, but one thing is I can't add animation to run the progress, I used the `strokeEnd` :|

Comment: Yes, for a rendering like this, you'd have to animate yourself, e.g., with `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: ok thanks @Rob ^^

Comment: I was able to do a full donut chart from the second approach, only the gaps between the slices are missing. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, I directed you to this answer as an illustration of the two corner rounding techniques (and to help visualize the first, in particular). But the above was not worrying about gaps between the arcs. So at the very least, where this does the `asin(cornerRadius / (innerRadius + cornerRadius))`, instead of `cornerRadius`, the numerator would be `(cornerRadius + gapInPixels / 2)`. Or you would just inset the start and end angles by `gapInRadians / 2`.